# Unable to bind sqlite statement for SELECT command

Tags: swift, sqlite, bind

In Swift I am connecting to a sqlite database and want to run a select statement:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select OneWord from words where OneWord='?' and definition='';", -1, &statement, nil) // Returns SQLITE_OK
```

But when I try to bind the variable:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, "Hello", -1, nil)
```

It tells me:
`Query prepare error: column index out of range`

This works well with an INSERT statement. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your  &statement is an insert statement? You will use sqlite3_bind_text to bind the value in insert statement.

Comment: No, statement is a select statement (see prepare command in my code)

Comment: Look in the example here .   https://www.raywenderlich.com/6620276-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is the quotes around the question mark, change your query string to

```
"select OneWord from words where OneWord = ? and definition = '';"
```

With the  quotes you are querying for rows where `OneWord` is equal to "?"